# Why does Modernizr set drag and drop class for iOS devices

Tags: ios, html, modernizr

Anyone know why Modernizr sets the class draganddrop on iOS devices? It's kinda hard to drag and drop a file in mobile Safari.

Is it a bug or feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modernizr issue #637](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/637) covers this

Basically, the browser is *technically* capable of drag and drop, but the operating system does not present any ux in a way that would allow for you to actually do it.